# Creating a leaderboard using TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, loops

Visual C#. Looking for a way to iterate through the labels of a TableLayoutPanel to show username and score. The list is sorted by score in descending order.

```
label1.Text = SortedList[0].Username; label2.Text = Convert.ToString(SortedList[0].Score);
label3.Text = SortedList[1].Username; label4.Text = Convert.ToString(SortedList[1].Score);
label5.Text = SortedList[2].Username; label6.Text = Convert.ToString(SortedList[2].Score);
//Continues until I have 10 rows.
```

I have written it like this to show that each line is a row. I hope that makes what I am trying to achieve here more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like this: (sorry it has been awhile since I have done WinForms)

```
var userNameLabels = Label[10]{label1, label3, label5,....}
var userScocreLabels = Label[10]{label2, label4, label6,....}

for(int i = 0; i <= SortedList.Count(); i++){
    userNameLabels[i].Text = SortedList[i].Username;
    userScocreLabels[i].Text = SortedList[i].Score.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jason. I didn't think of an array of type label, much appreciated.

Comment: Not a problem mate

Answer (score 0):

I think right tool for this job is `DataGridView`

```
//below property is true by default - will generate columns for properties automatically
yourDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
yourDataGridView.DataSource = SortedList;
```